# How to model these data? (zero inflated, positive skew,

Tags: regression, skewness, zero-inflation

[image: histogram]
 -

The variable depicted in the histogram is a sum of 11 items.  Each item asks about the frequency of occurrence of a particular type of event (a negative consequence of drinking) on the following scale:
0 = Never 1 = Once  2 = Twice  3 = 3-5 times  4 = 6-9 times  5 = 10 or more times

Anything lower than 0 shown on the histogram is an error and will be deleted prior to analysis.

My goal is to test whether an interaction of two predictors of this variable is significant.  I've considered a zero-inflated Poisson and hurdle models, but even without the 0's the remaining data are not normal and Box-Cox failed to make it look anything like normal data.  It's not exactly count data so Poisson does not seem to apply, nor does it look like Poisson or negative binomial (I could be wrong about this - open to all suggestions!).  A reference will be helpful/necessary to justify whatever method is recommended.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried  fitting a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#/media/File:Gamma_distribution_pdf.svg)

Comment: If the items in your sum are all positive, how are you getting negative values? Also, why are you emphasizing that you need a normal distribution? In other words, what does a Poisson zero-inflated model have anything to do with normal data?

Comment: You should fix negatives before adding, rather than after.

Comment: If you data is strictly non negative, and measure the times that an event happens, I think the way to go is fitting a negative exponential. As test try to make the logarithm of the bins and check if you can fit a straight line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  If fitting a gamma, 1) how can I tell whether it is appropriate or not - is there a reference I can use to justify it? and 2) how to think about whether or not to log-transform the data?

Comment: Also, is it appropriate to add 1 to each observation to allow inclusion of participants whose scores are 0?  (since 0 is not in the support of the gamma distribution)

Comment: What about using quantile regression predicting the median?